# My content <p> to shrink on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my content text to shrink on mobile devices. My footer, header and forms shrink but my text on my privacy pages and such wont. Is there an easy way to do this. Thanks

```css
.content {
border: 1px solid transparent;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 40px;
padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
width: 1000px;
}

.content a {
color: #0996f8;  
font-family: Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 28px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.content a:hover {
color: #0996f8;  
font-family: Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 28px;
text-decoration: underline;
}

.content p {
color: #221f1f;  
font-family: Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 28px;
}
```

Comment: Look into css breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

to make the content `shrink` you have multiple options of doing so.

> First: @media only rule,

with the @media only you can change the css depending on the screen `width` or `height`, therefor you could change the `font-size` to make the content fit, or make the whole `<p>` smaller changing the `width`

Example css with @media only would be:

> @media only screen and (max-width 767px){.content p{font-size: 14px;}}

or any other css setting like i mentioned.

> Second option:Setting a width for the `<p>` and use `word-break`

This is not better then the @media only rule, but it could surely work, you can give the `<p>` element or it's parent a `width`, and when the content doesn't fit in, it will enter a new row. with `word-break: break-word;` you can make sure it will only go to a new page as whole word and not just letter for letter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilise css media queries to target certain breakpoints. Here's an example

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .content p{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .content p{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .content p{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Ideally, when you start developing a new site, you want to create a style sheet with h1-h6, p, a, ul, ol, etc. Its not good practice to style p tags throughout the site, they should be controlled by one style, in one place.

If you're ever working on a 40+ page site and the client comes back and wants to change the parapraph size from 12px-14px, you only have to do this once, not multiple times throughout. Also it follows the DRY principle.

If you want to target different font sizes you can **encapsulate** the styles. For example, Say your paragraph tag is set to 16px. In the header and footer you want the paragraph tag to be 21px. You can use very similar to your current class. You're calling the paragraph tag in the .content class, so you need to call the p tag in the .header or .footer class

So for the header, footer you can use something like this.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .header p,
    .footer p{
        font-size: 21px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it to work as I googled css breakpoints. Is there a way to keep my footer and header full width. Thanks

Comment: if you did not touch the footer and header css within the breakpoint css, it should not be changing width

Answer (score 0):

First, remove duplicate properties that have already been declared in '.content p' from other classes. This will eliminate any chance of having your mobile CSS overridden by these things.

Add a CSS media query right below the '.content p' class to detect the width of the browser and change the font size accordingly.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.content p {  
font-size: /* New size here */; 
}
}
```

This will cause the font size to change when a browser's width is less than 600px.

Comment: the @media will always overrule other css, only `!important` can mess it up. therefor removing duplicate properties is not necessary, but always a good plan to clean up your code :P

Comment: You're right @RamondeVries. I was thinking that their CSS for the a tags might override the @ media here.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you are asking to have the content shrink on smaller screens. A common way for this to be achieved without needing to do a whole lot in the media query department is to use the `rem` unit, and to use CSS' media queries to change the font-size property on the HTML tag, thereby updating all the other tags.

[Some Breakpoints to look at](https://medium.com/@uiuxlab/the-most-used-responsive-breakpoints-in-2017-of-mine-9588e9bd3a8a) (keep in mind, this is one dude, so do some other searches for common device breakpoints)

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.content a {
  color: #0996f8;
  font-family: Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content a:hover {
  color: #0996f8;
  font-family: Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.content p {
  color: #221f1f;
  font-family: Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 28px;
}

html {
  font-size: 17px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

@media (max-width: 414px) {
  html {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2>Title 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique atque ea ex libero non vero expedita quas numquam aut sunt.</p>
  <p>Laudantium accusamus aliquid libero minus neque inventore esse, ipsam eligendi, placeat harum, quibusdam dolorum unde quidem, consequatur commodi possimus sed.</p>
  <p>Aliquid vitae blanditiis laudantium et eaque vel beatae delectus, est quos consequuntur quasi, possimus, facilis velit earum nulla ad quaerat.</p>
  <p>Culpa tenetur, praesentium obcaecati placeat. Tempore expedita, delectus explicabo facilis, repudiandae non. Illum a accusamus suscipit, corrupti eligendi, ducimus itaque.</p>
  <p>Accusamus labore facere asperiores unde soluta vitae, fugit, vero architecto dignissimos iusto ducimus rem et quia similique quas quis nihil.</p>
  <p>Labore asperiores animi, necessitatibus reprehenderit quasi laborum, quaerat! Ducimus ab sapiente reiciendis dolorum, quasi quas voluptatem, officiis nostrum natus sed.</p>
  <p>Pariatur optio at maxime id tempora, molestias accusamus enim maiores dolorem assumenda distinctio eius facere explicabo adipisci placeat deleniti culpa.</p>
  <p>Veritatis quos omnis, nemo exercitationem enim architecto consequatur fuga labore voluptate possimus dolor quas perferendis provident recusandae consequuntur, ullam tenetur.</p>
  <p>Maiores exercitationem illum incidunt culpa, deserunt ex excepturi consequatur, modi officia blanditiis expedita esse repellendus id reiciendis laboriosam molestiae dignissimos.</p>
  <p>Modi sunt magni hic nesciunt aperiam provident assumenda sequi, reiciendis inventore est fuga voluptatem eos, ipsam mollitia laboriosam quidem quasi.</p>
</div>
```

Another way would be to use CSS Variables, and using the same media query trick to simply update the variable on smaller screens. This would be nice because then you could have different sizes that you update independently based on screen size for a more optimal look and feel. This does, however, carry some overhead.

A rough example is below, but please look up [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) a bit on your own.

```
:root {
    --font-size: 16px;
}

.item { 
    font-size: var(--font-size);
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    :root {
        --font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```